# Replace last occurrence of a string in a string

Tags: php, string

Anyone know of a very fast way to replace the last occurrence of a string with another string in a string?

Note, **the last occurrence of the string might not be the last characters in the string.**

Example:

```
$search = 'The';
$replace = 'A';
$subject = 'The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog';
```

Expected Output:

```
The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over A Lazy Dog
```

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->replaceLast($search, $replace)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L305) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

    if($pos !== false)
    {
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: This was still returning true no matter what. Consider modifying it to be:     if($pos)
    {
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
     return $subject;
    }
    else 
    {
     return false;
    }

Comment: @Jason It doesn't return `TRUE` no matter what. It returns a string no matter what. If a replacement can't be made it returns the original `$subject`, just like [`substr_replace `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) do.

Comment: @Mischa Isn't that the same thing in this case? I was attempting to do something like !str_lreplace, but if it doesn't return false, it's considered true, right? Either way, this helped me out and I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason, glad it helped. Yes, a string is *truthy*, but it's not the same as `TRUE`. Anyway, I get your point. In this answer I tried to follow what PHP does in similar functions, but you are of course free to use the implementation suggested by yourself if you want to use `!str_lreplace`.

Comment: How can this work? `strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string` - edit: wow. Php geniuses really made a function called `strpos` and `strrpos` ? Thanks....

Comment: @Barry this is one case where PHP does not deserve the blame :-) The names are patterned on the decades-old `strstr`, [`strrstr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strrstr) of the standard C library, which are the same functions. (But did they _have_ to change the name?)

Comment: In case we just want to replace the last character, we don't need strrpos since we already know the position. We can just do $position = strlen($subject) - 1; and if ($subject[$position] == $search) before using substr_replace.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but this won't work with arrays (like `str_replace` does), as strrpos can only accept strings as arguments.

Answer (score 32):

Another 1-liner but without preg:

```
$subject = 'bourbon, scotch, beer';
$search = ',';
$replace = ', and';

echo strrev(implode(strrev($replace), explode(strrev($search), strrev($subject), 2))); //output: bourbon, scotch, and beer
```

Comment: FWIW, the accepted solution is roughly 35% faster than this solution.

Comment: I would always chose a regex function over 6 function calls.  I can't imagine seeing this technique employed in professional code.

Answer (score 27):

```
$string = 'this is my world, not my world';
$find = 'world';
$replace = 'farm';
$result = preg_replace(strrev("/$find/"),strrev($replace),strrev($string),1);
echo strrev($result); //output: this is my world, not my farm
```

Comment: Why it works with all strings reversed? Is there some (I assume) specific performance gain when using regular-expressions?

Comment: No it actually decreases performance but it's because you want the last occurrence only so you limit the search to one and reverse everything if you wanted the first you wouldn't have to reverse anything

Answer (score 20):

The following rather compact solution uses the [PCRE positive lookahead assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to match the last occurrence of the substring of interest, that is, an occurrence of the substring which is not followed by any other occurrences of the same substring. Thus the example replaces the `last 'fox'` with `'dog'`.

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox, fox, fox jumps over the lazy fox!!!';
echo preg_replace('/(fox(?!.*fox))/', 'dog', $string);
```

OUTPUT:

```
The quick brown fox, fox, fox jumps over the lazy dog!!!
```

Comment: I don't understand why this later answer has received more upvotes than [Alix Axel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3837298/2943403).  This pattern take 3 times as many "steps" compared to Alix's pattern.  The negative lookahead is an unnecessary expense because it doesn't improve accuracy at all -- versus greedy dot matching.

Answer (score 13):

You could do this:

```
$str = 'Hello world';
$str = rtrim($str, 'world') . 'John';
```

Result is  'Hello John';

Comment: This works as long as there isn't any repeated characters. In my situation I'm striping the page number off the archive date so I have "2015-12/2" and it takes all / and all 2 off the end becoming "2015-1".

Comment: This will only work if the last occurrence searched is the last word and has no additional chars after it.

Comment: This doesn't work because [`rtrim`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) doesn't behave the way you're thinking.  It will strip from the end any characters that exist in the search string in whatever order (and always append the replacement), e.g. "Hello word" -> "Hello John", "Hello lord" -> "Hello John", "Hello motor" -> "Hello motJohn", "Hello worldy" -> "Hello worldyJohn".

Comment: I don't recommend that anyone use this (unexplained) code which is prone to quietly failing.  This answer makes no attempt to "find" the last occurrence of a string -- it just keeps consuming characters from the right side of the input string while the character mask is satisfied.  This does the same thing: `rtrim($str, 'dlorw')`

Answer (score 10):

This is an ancient question, but why is everyone overlooking the simplest regexp-based solution? Normal regexp quantifiers are greedy, people! If you want to find the last instance of a pattern, just stick `.*` in front of it. Here's how:

```
$text = "The quick brown fox, fox, fox, fox, jumps over etc.";
$fixed = preg_replace("((.*)fox)", "$1DUCK", $text);
print($fixed);
```

This will replace the *last* instance of "fox" to "DUCK", like it's supposed to, and print:

```
The quick brown fox, fox, fox, DUCK, jumps over etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! The perfect function to wrap around my expression to accomplish this. In my case I'm replacing the last comma with ", and ". Glad I scrolled down a bit in this answer list.

Comment: The "simplest regexp-based solution" was "overlooked" by you -- this technique was [posted 8 years earlier on this page by Alix Axel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3837298/2943403). His/Her answer is identical except his/her snippet is dynamic.  Your answer has hardcoded the needle into the search pattern and the replacement string into the replace parameter.  I have gone one step further to simplify the replacement by using the `\K` character [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64876047/2943403)

Comment: @mickmackusa, you're right, good catch. Indeed Alix Axel's answer uses greedy search on the left... but let's just say I don't see it as particularly "simple" :-D. (Also there is no reason to use ~ as the delimiter... just makes things more confusing.)

Comment: I would argue that your parenthetical delimiters are more confusing _to me_ -- and I am very comfortable with reading regex.  I often use tildes as delimiters, even if there are no forward slashes in the pattern -- it is my personal preference.  Seeing parentheses in a pattern, my mind assumes a capture group or lookaround.  Alix's answer IS less simple mostly because it is dynamic.  My answer tightens up the syntax slightly.

Comment: the parens _are_ a capture group.

Answer (score 7):

This will also work:

```
function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    return preg_replace('~(.*)' . preg_quote($search, '~') . '(.*?)~', '$1' . $replace . '$2', $subject, 1);
}
```

**UPDATE** Slightly more concise version (http://ideone.com/B8i4o):

```
function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    return preg_replace('~(.*)' . preg_quote($search, '~') . '~', '$1' . $replace, $subject, 1);
}
```

Comment: Am i doing it wrong ? If so just ignore me :) ||| echo str_lreplace("x", "y", "this x or that x"); => Output: "y" See: http://www.ideone.com/UXuTo

Comment: @edorian: Oops! Sorry, I posted that in a hurry, the correct version is here: http://ideone.com/vR073.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use strrpos() to find last match.

```
$string = "picture_0007_value";
$findChar =strrpos($string,"_");

$string[$findChar]=".";

echo $string;
```

Output : picture_0007.value

Comment: This is only correct when replacing a single-byte character string which has a length of one AND the search character exists -- in all other cases, this fails.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "picture_0007_value";
$findChar =strrpos($string,"_");
if($findChar !== FALSE) {
  $string[$findChar]=".";
}

echo $string;
```

Apart from the mistakes in the code, Faruk Unal has the best anwser. One function does the trick.

Comment: You need to check, if **$findChar** is not false (same way as in the accepted answer). If the string does not contain searched string, you get notice and the first character will be replaced.

Comment: This is great, but as it stands it can only replace 1 character with 1 character.

Comment: The above comments are correct. This is only correct when replacing a single-byte character string which has a length of one.

Answer (score 2):

Shorthand for accepted answer

```
function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject){ 
    return is_numeric($pos=strrpos($subject,$search))?
    substr_replace($subject,$replace,$pos,strlen($search)):$subject;
}
```

Comment: This is also less readable than the accepted answer.  Why not use a better coding standard? Please read the PSR coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

A short version:

```
$NewString = substr_replace($String,$Replacement,strrpos($String,$Replace),strlen($Replace));
```

Comment: This unexplained "short version" (less readable version) should not be used because if the needle (`$Replace`) is not found, then the string (`$String`) is unintentionally damaged/mutated.  This is a mistake that earlier answers did not make.  This answer should be removed so that researchers do not copy this inappropriate snippet.  https://3v4l.org/easUY

Answer (score 0):

While using regex is typically less performant than non-regex techniques, I do appreciate the control and flexibility that it affords.

In my snippet, I will set the pattern to be case-insensitive (`\i`, although my sample input will not challenge this rule) and include word boundaries (`\b`, although they were not explicitly called for).

I am also going to use the `\K` metacharacter to reset the fullstring match so that no capture groups / backreferences are needed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/P5dCb))

```
$search = 'The';
$replace = 'A';
$subject = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog's Thermos!";

echo preg_replace(
         '/.*\K\b' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '\b/i',
         $replace,
         $subject
     );
```

Output:

```
  The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over A Lazy Dog's Thermos!
# ^^^                            ^            ^^^
# not replaced                replaced        not replaced
```

---

Without word boundaries: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Q8InS))

```
echo preg_replace(
         '/.*\K' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '/i',
         $replace,
         $subject
     );
```

Output:

```
  The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog's Armos!
# ^^^                            ^^^            ^
# not replaced              not replaced        replaced
```

Comment: Don't confuse strings with words. Words are space-delimited strings, strings can be parts of words. The right code should convert "Thermos" to "Aermos" and leave "The Lazy" untouched.

Comment: Yes.  I am deliberately using word boundaries although not asked for.  There was no [mcve] from the OP so we won't know if case sensitivity and word boundaries are necessary.  I am being generous and offering several new techniques to the page which researchers may want.  I can extend my answer and add another snippet without boundaries if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Below corrected zack's code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11144999/9996503).
Be careful with regular expressions! Consider this:

```
$string = 'Round brackets (parentheses) "()", square brackets "()"';
$find = '()';
$replace = '[]';
// Zack's code:
$result = preg_replace(strrev("/$find/"),strrev($replace),strrev($string),1);
var_dump($result); // Output: NULL
// Correct code:
$result = strrev(preg_replace('/'.preg_quote(strrev($find)).'/', strrev($replace), strrev($string), 1));
echo $result; //Output: Round brackets (parentheses) "()", square brackets "[]"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the "$" on a reg expression to match the end of the string

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fox';
echo preg_replace('/fox$/', 'dog', $string);

//output
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Comment: this works only if the last occurence is in the end of the string http://ideone.com/nbNSNq

Comment: This will not work if any other characters appear after the last 'fox'.

Answer (score -1):

For the interested: I've written a function that utilises preg_match so that you're able to replace from right hand side using regex.

```
function preg_rreplace($search, $replace, $subject) {
    preg_match_all($search, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $lastMatch = end($matches);

    if ($lastMatch && false !== $pos = strrpos($subject, $lastMatchedStr = $lastMatch[0])) {
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($lastMatchedStr));
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

Or as a shorthand combination/implementation of both options:

```
function str_rreplace($search, $replace, $subject) {
    return (false !== $pos = strrpos($subject, $search)) ?
        substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search)) : $subject;
}
function preg_rreplace($search, $replace, $subject) {
    preg_match_all($search, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    return ($lastMatch = end($matches)) ? str_rreplace($lastMatch[0], $replace, $subject) : $subject;
}
```

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835653/3017716 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23343396/3017716

Comment: The preg_ technique generates warnings and should not be used. https://3v4l.org/lNU8R