# Replacing the last occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: php

I have a little issue I'm trying to find a solution for.

Basically, imagine you have the following string:

```
    $string = 'Hello I am a string';
```

And you'd like it to end with something like the folowing:

```
    $string = 'Hello I am a&nbsp;string';
```

Simply, replacing the last occurrence of a space, with a non-breaking space.

I'm doing this because I don't want the last word in a heading to be on its own. Simply because when it comes to headings:

```
 Hello I am a
 string
```

Doesn't look as good as

```
 Hello I am
 a string
```

How does one do such a thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string

Comment: That last word is called an [orphan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans).

Comment: Correct! ppl in print land are familiar with the term.. i didn't think it would be too recognised here. But yeah, can't have orphans... they are sad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/\s(\S*)$/', '&nbsp;$1', 'Hello I am a string');
```

#### Output

```
Hello I am a&nbsp;string
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/niAKG2xQ).

`\s` matches whitespace characters. To match a space explictly, put one in (and change `\S` to `[^ ]`).

Comment: If input is not trimmed, I would use `/\s(\S+)\s*$/` as a pattern, as `'/\s(\S*)$/'` would change `"some string "` into `"some string&nbsp;"` rather than `"some&nbsp;string"`. It might also be good to handle multiple spaces, i.e., `some  string` (2 spaces between words) should be converted to `some&nbsp;string` rather than `some &nbsp;string`, so pattern would be `/\s+(\S+)\s*$/`.

Answer (score 22):

Code from [this example](http://www.philmcauley.com/posts/quick-tip-replace-last-occurrence-of-a-string-in-php/) will do the trick:

```
// $subject is the original string
// $search is the thing you want to replace
// $replace is what you want to replace it with

substr_replace($subject, $replace, strrpos($subject, $search), strlen($search));
```

Comment: It will only work as expected, if `$subject` actually contains at least one occurence of `$search`. Otherwise `strrpos($subject, $search)` will return `false`, that will be interpreted as `0` and the first `strlen($search)` characters of `$subject` will replaced by `$replace`. Ergo: the function call needs to be wrapped with an `if`: `if(strrpos($subject, $search) !== false) { ... }`

Comment: The link is now broken if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:

```
$string = preg_replace('/([\s\S]+)\s(\w)$/','$1&nbsp;$2',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

as per pounndifdef's answer, however i needed to decode the `&nbsp;` HTML entity like so:

```
substr_replace($subject, html_entity_decode($replace), strrpos($subject, $search), strlen($search));
```

also worked using alex's answer:

```
preg_replace('/\s(\S*)$/', html_entity_decode('&nbsp;').'$1', 'Hello I am a string');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace()` like normal, but reverse the string first.  Then, reverse it back.