# PHP string find and replace until last instance

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string in a DB table which is separated by a comma i.e. this,is,the,first,sting

What I would like to do and don't know how is to have the string outputted like:
this, is, the, first and string

Note the spaces and the last comma is replaced by the word 'and'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be your solution:

```
$str = 'this,is,the,first,string';
$str = str_replace(',', ', ', $str);
echo preg_replace('/(.*),/', '$1 and', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

First use, the function provided in this answer: [PHP Replace last occurrence of a String in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string)

```
function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

    if($pos === false)
    {
        return $subject;
    }
    else
    {
        return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }
}
```

Then, you should perform a common str_replace on text to replace all other commas:

```
$string = str_lreplace(',', 'and ', $string);
str_replace(',',', ',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = explode( ',', $string );
$output_string = '';
for( $x = 0; $x < count($words); x++ ){
    if( $x == 0 ){
        $output = $words[$x];
    }else if( $x == (count($words) - 1) ){
        $output .= ', and ' . $words[$x]; 
    }else{
        $output .= ', ' . $words[$x];
    }
}
```