# PHP strip_tags only at the end of the string

Tags: php, string, strip-tags

Ok, well, I just want to use `strip_tags` function on the very end of a string to get rid of any `<br />` tags.

Here's what I have now, but this is no good because it strips these tags from everywhere in the string, which is not what I want.  I only need them stripped out if it's at the end of the string...

```
$string = strip_tags($string, strtr($string, array('<br />' => '&#10;')));
```

How can I do this same thing, except only at the very end of a string??

Thanks guys!!

Comment: You could use `preg_replace()` and the `$` anchor if it's the last part of your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string) like:

```
$string = str_lreplace("<br />", "", $string);
```

You may also replace standard HTML breaks as well:

```
$string = str_lreplace("<br />", "", $string);
$string = str_lreplace("<br>", "", $string);
```

Comment: But the last tag may or may not be a `<br />` to be stripped.  It should only strip `<br />` tags.

Comment: Ah, you may then use this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string. I will update my answer.

Comment: No, that link doesn't help for my situation...  It's weird, but it doesn't work at all.  I need it to get rid of it only at the end of the string, if it exists at the very end, after all of the text of the string is done...

Comment: It works for me: it finds and replaces the last occurrence of a substring within in a string.

Comment: No, it needs to replace it only in the last couple of characters of the string, at the very end.  It should not replace it if it exists within the string, but not within the last few characters...

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I got this figured out, will mark as solved, even though this code doesn't solve the problem, I managed to edit it and solve the problem on my own.  Cheers :)

Comment: what is `str_lreplace` - I can't find such a method. did you mean `str_replace` ?

Comment: You should visit the link that Connor posted up in his answer first.  Than you might understand...

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the last occurence of the `<br/>` and remove it:

```
$index = strrpos($string, '<br/>');
if($index == strlen($string)-5){
    $string= substr($string,0,$index);
}
```

Comment: Forget it, you are missing the point.  I don't need the last occurence, I need the last 5 or 6 characters.  Anyways, I got this figured out.  Thanks to all of you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: In that case it's even easier: `$string=substr($string,0,strlen($string)-5);`

Comment: That will remove the last 5 characters...  Not what I want...  I have answered my own question.  Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @SolomonClosson that's a small correction (see updated answer). But, if there isn't any answer that solved your problem, and you did find an answer - it will be nice of you to post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the method that I am using and this works exactly as I want it to work...

```
$search = strrpos($string, '<br />');
if($search !== false && $search == strlen($string) - 6)
    $string = substr_replace($string, '', $search, 6);
```

I achieved this answer by looking at the link that Connor Pete posted up, so the code at that link helped me to achieve the end result located here.

Honestly, I'm not even really looking for a `<br />` tag.  I just posted that up for the sake of argument.  The main problem I am facing is that I have an unclosed bold tag `<b` that spits out at the end of a string that shouldn't be there, cause when written to the document, it causes the rest of the page to be in bold!  So, honestly, this was changed to this:

```
$replace = strrpos($string, '<b');
if($replace !== false && $replace == strlen($string) - 2)
    $string = substr_replace($string, '', $replace, 2);
```

Thanks for all of your help on this matter :)