# Get the last occurrence of String, as a number, and replace it

Tags: php, regex, string, php-5.3

I have strings like this

```
Foo(2)moreFoo (1)
Foo(1)moreFoo (2)
Foo(99)moreFoo (3)
Foo(99)moreFoo (9)
Foo
```

I need to take each string, and change the last `(number)`

So, in this case, I would like to get for each string:

```
Foo(2)moreFoo (2)
Foo(1)moreFoo (3)
Foo(99)moreFoo (4)
Foo(99)moreFoo (10)
Foo(1)
```

It would be like get the string, get the last occurence of `(number)`, and replace it by `(number +1)`

How can I do this?

I've checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string), but not sure how to change it.

I've started with

```
$subject = 'Foo (2)(1)';

if(preg_match('\([0-9]+\)', $subject))
{   
    $pos = strrpos($subject, '\([0-9]+\)');

    if($pos !== false)
    {
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }
}
```

but the problem is that could be that the number will be (10) so, I cannot just get the last 3 characters.

The `(number)`, if exists, will be at end. It could be at middle, but the interesting one is in the end.

Comment: have you tried using `$` to match the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to target the individual matches and replace them:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\((\d+)\)$/m', function($match) {
    return '(' . ++$match[1] . ')';
}, $subject);
```

The pattern matches a parenthesized number at the end of each line and calls the anonymous function to perform the replacement. It uses `$` combined with the `/m` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to match the end of each line.

Matching lines that don't have any `(number)` you need a somewhat trickier expression:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(?:\((\d+)\)|([^)]))$/m', function($match) {
    return isset($match[2]) ? "{$match[2]}(1)" : '(' . ++$match[1] . ')';
}, $subject);
```

The alternation matches either a `(number)` or something that's not a `)` at the end of the line. If the line didn't end with `)` we should add `(1)`.

Comment: wow. Amazing !! Exactly what I need !! Just to improve the answer, I changed the index of $match to `$match[count($match) - 1]`. This is because we also have to consider cases like `Foo(1)(2)(3)` and get `Foo(1)(2)(4)`. Anyway I didn't specify in the question. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gonzalo.- My code should already do that properly, because it only matches the last one. In fact, `$match` always has two array items.

Comment: you're right. I though that it will return all the matches. Thanks

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Btw, the last line of your input doesn't have a `(number)` at the end; should it add `(1)` if there's none?

Comment: yes I already did it on my own, but add it in the answer. Just an if, I guess

Answer (score 0):

You'll use preg_match_all() instead of preg_match() since we want the last match. This will get you ready to use a function like you mentioned, but you'll still need to strip the parens and add 1.

```
$subject = 'Foo (2)(1)';

echo $subject,"<br />";

if(preg_match_all('/\([0-9]+\)/', $subject, $matches))
{   
    $last_match =  $matches[0][count($matches[0])-1];
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $last_match);

    echo $pos;
    if($pos !== false)
    {
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
    }
}
```