# PHP's preg_match() returns the position of the last match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

With

```
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

is it possible to search a string in reverse? I.e., return the position of the last occurrence of the pattern in the subject similar to `strripos`.

Or do I have to return the position of all matches with `preg_match_all` and use the last element of `$matches`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

PHP doesn't have a regex method that search a string from right to left (like in [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)). There are several possible recipes to solve that (this list isn't exhaustive, but it may provide ideas for your own workaround):

- using [`preg_match_all`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag and [`end($matches)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) will give you the last match set
- reversing the string with [`strrev`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) and building a "reversed" pattern to be used with preg_match
- using [`preg_match`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and building a pattern anchored at the end of the string that ensures there is no more occurrences of the searched mask until the end of the string
- using a greedy quantifier before the target and `\K` to start the match result at the position you want. Once the end of the string is reached, the regex engine will backtrack until it finds a match.

---

Examples with the string `$str = 'xxABC1xxxABC2xx'` for the pattern `/x[A-Z]+\d/`

**Way 1**: *find all matches and displays the last.*

```
if ( preg_match_all('/x[A-Z]+\d/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) )
    print_r(end($matches)[0]);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/s7jZ8)

**Way 2**: *find the first match of the reversed string with a reversed pattern, and displays the reversed result.*

```
if ( preg_match('/\d[A-Z]+x/', strrev($str), $match) )
    print_r(strrev($match[0]));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/DS8K3)

Note that it isn't always so easy to reverse a pattern.

**Way 3**: *Jumps from x to x and checks with the negative lookahead if there's no other `x[A-Z]+\d` matches from the end of the string.*

```
if ( preg_match('/x[A-Z]+\d(?!.*x[A-Z]+\d)/', $str, $match) )
    print_r($match[0]);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1tHKH)

**Variants**:

With a lazy quantifier

```
if ( preg_match('/x[A-Z]+\d(?!.*?x[A-Z]+\d)/', $str, $match) )
    print_r($match[0]);
```

or with a *"tempered quantifier"*

```
if ( preg_match('/x[A-Z]+\d(?=(?:(?!x[A-Z]+\d).)*$)/', $str, $match) )
    print_r($match[0]);
```

It can be interesting to choose between these variants when you know in advance where a match has the most probabilities to occur.

**Way 4**: *goes to the end of the string and backtracks until it finds a `x[A-Z]+\d` match. The `\K` removes the start of the string from the match result.*

```
if ( preg_match('/^.*\Kx[A-Z]+\d/', $str, $match) )
    print_r($match[0]);
```

**Way 4 (a more hand-driven variant)**: *to limit backtracking steps, you can greedily advance from the start of the string, atomic group by atomic group, and backtrack in the same way by atomic groups, instead of by characters.*

```
if ( preg_match('/^(?>[^x]*\Kx)+[A-Z]+\d/', $str, $match) )
    print_r($match[0]);
```

Comment: Went with the fist method, I don't know if there is some unnecessary expense in returning all matches but it works fine

Comment: Great answer sir.

Answer (score 4):

"Greedy" is the keyword here.
`*` is by default greedy, and `*?` limits greediness to the bare minimum.

So the solution is to use the combination, e.g. (searching for last period followed by a whitespace),

```
/^.*\.\s(.*?)$/s
```

- `^` is the beginning of text
- `.*` eats as much as it can, including matching patterns
- `\\.\s` is the period followed by a whitespace (what I am looking for)
- `(.*?)` eats as little as possible. Capture group () so I could address it as a match group.
- `$` end of text
- `s` - makes sure newlines are ignored (not treated as `$` and `^` - `.` (dot) matches newline)

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand exactly what you want, because it depends on how many groups will be captured.

I made a function to capture the offset of the last capture according to the group number. In my pattern, I have three groups: the first group, full capture and the other two groups, sub-groups.

Pattern sample code:

```
$pattern = "/<a[^\x3e]{0,}href=\x22([^\x22]*)\x22>([^\x3c]*)<\/a>/";
```

HTML sample code:

```
$subject = '<ul>
<li>Search Engines</li>
<li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.bing.com/">Bing</a></li>
<li><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/">DuckDuckGo</a></li>
</ul>';
```

My function captures the offset of the last element and you have the possibility to indicate the number of matching:

```
function get_offset_last_match( $pattern, $subject, $number ) {
    if ( preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ) == false ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $matches[$number][count( $matches[0] ) - 1][1];
}
```

You can get detailed information about preg_match_all [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) on official documentation.

Using my pattern for example:

0 => all text
1 => href value
2 => innerHTML

```
echo '<pre>';
echo get_offset_last_match( $pattern, $subject, 0 ) . PHP_EOL; // all text
echo get_offset_last_match( $pattern, $subject, 1 ) . PHP_EOL; // href value
echo get_offset_last_match( $pattern, $subject, 2 ) . PHP_EOL; // innerHTML
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

The output is:

```
140
149
174
```

My function (text):

```
function get_text_last_match( $pattern, $subject, $number ) {
    if ( preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ) == false ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $matches[$number][count( $matches[0] ) - 1][0];
}
```

Sample code:

```
echo '<textarea style="font-family: Consolas: font-size: 14px; height: 200px; tab-size: 4; width: 90%;">';
echo 'ALL   = ' . get_text_last_match( $pattern, $subject, 0 ) . PHP_EOL; // all text
echo 'HREF  = ' . get_text_last_match( $pattern, $subject, 1 ) . PHP_EOL; // href value
echo 'INNER = ' . get_text_last_match( $pattern, $subject, 2 ) . PHP_EOL; // innerHTML
echo '</textarea>';
```

The output is:

```
ALL   = <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/">DuckDuckGo</a>
HREF  = https://duckduckgo.com/
INNER = DuckDuckGo
```

Answer (score -1):

preg_match() does not support reverse searching because it is not necessary.

You can create a regular expression that contains a greedy (that is default) lookahead that matches anything (like `(?<=.*)stuff`). This way, you should get the last occurrence of your match.

Detailed information from official documentation is in *[preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)*.

Comment: `(?<=.*)` is a lookbehind and unlimited length lookbehinds are not supported by php.

Comment: correct, I mixed the two names, sorry. I wasn't aware that php does not support that.

Comment: So, presumably this answer in incorrect. The regular expression wasn't changed.