# Truncate a string after the last number

Tags: php

I want to truncate a string to remove anything after the last digit. For example:

`GB67 7HG` - I want it to truncate to `GB67 7`. Preferably, I would still like the space within the string.

I am unsure where to start!

Comment: try with rtrim($text, 'A..Z');

Comment: possible duplicate of [php preg\_match return position of last match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343087/php-preg-match-return-position-of-last-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using regular expressions

```
preg_match('/(.*?)(\d+)(?!.*\d)/', 'GB67 7HG', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => GB67 7
    [1] => GB67 
    [2] => 7
)
```

[PHP Demo](http://ideone.com/5OOMRp) | [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sK8gC4/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you have only numbers and chars, you can use rtrim to trim unnecessary chars like `$text = rtrim($text, 'A..Z ');`

More for this function at: http://php.net//manual/bg/function.rtrim.php

You can use regex too, but then you need some regex skills to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a cleaner solution using regular expressions, but perhaps the following will help. Simply finding the index of the last digit and using substr().

```
$string = 'GB67 7HG';
$count = strlen($string);
$index = -1;
$i = 0;
while( $i < $count ) {
    if( ctype_digit($string[$i]) ) {
        $index = $i;
    }
    $i++;
}
if($index != -1) echo substr($string, 0, $index + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you @Baps, this worked perfectly, but I chose to go with the regex for simplicity sake!