# replacing a character at a certain pos in the str using php

Tags: php

exp. string to replace;

```
 150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers_jpg
```

I need to replace the character `_jpg` with `.jpg` but the extension can change so I need `_` to be replaced with a point.  I have tried `strpos` and then `substr_replace` but this removes everything after and include the `_`.

Comment: You should take a look at [PHP Replace Last Occurence of a String in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string). This will show you how to change only the last instance of the underscore without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code

```
$imgExt = array('_jpg','_jpeg','_png','_bmp','_gif');
$replaceExt = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.bmp','.gif');
$string = '150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers_jpg';
$replacedText = str_replace($imgExt,$replaceExt,$string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested with 2 extensions and also accounts for jpeg

```
$str1 = '150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers_jpg';
$str2 = '150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers_png';

$str1 = preg_replace('/_([a-z]{3,4})$/', '.$1', $str1);
$str2 = preg_replace('/_([a-z]{3,4})$/', '.$1', $str2);

echo $str1; //150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers.jpg
echo $str2; //150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) command.

```
$string = '150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers_jpg';
$new = '.jpg' // or wathever you want.
$new_string = str_replace('_jpg', $new, $string);
```

Comment: This will also replace _jpg if it's anywhere else in string. And also questioner wanted a solution for other file formats too

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$filename = "150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers_jpg";
$position = strrpos($filename, "_");
if($position !== false) {
    $filename = substr_replace($filename, ".", $position, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$o = "150941_3D-glass-green-effect-hd-wallpapers_jpg";
$o = preg_replace("/_([^_]+)$/", ".\\1", $o);
echo $o;
```

Comment: does not work.  it replace's the _ in the beginnen too.

Comment: this solution will replace every "_" in the string.

Comment: fixed bug in the code