# Use PHP to strip 1st <p> and last </p> only in a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have found a number of preg_replace solutions for this problem, the closest one being this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>(.*)<\/p[^>]*>/i', '$1', $string);
```

However, this strips ALL `<p>` & `</p>` tags. How do I adjust this to ONLY strip the FIRST `<p>` and LAST `</p>` tags, even if there other such tags positioned elsewhere in my string?

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't use a regex to process HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string is applicable if you edit it

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Well, technically it is a string (TS said so). Given enough constraints, regexp and html go together just fine. Besides, Chuck Norris can parse html with regexp. ;)

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet Yes, I just want to warn him for the "let's-use-a-regex-to-parse-HTML" route of solving problems. And of course Chuck Norris can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an extra parameter as 1.
See this post. [Using str_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

For last p tag use search from behind. Or u can reverse the string search and replace from start then. Dont forget to change the regex accordingly.

Ur first regex could be like this

```
$str=preg_replace('/<p>/', '', $str,1);
```

Now reverse the string and do the same but change regex.

```
$str=strrev ($str);

$str=preg_replace('/>p\/</', '', $str,1);
```

Now reverse the string again

```
$str=strrev ($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering it will be time consuming to understand the code, I would just use str_replace as per these discussions:

[Using str_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

[PHP Replace last occurrence of a String in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string)

So something like:

```
// Remove first occurrence of '<p>'
$pos = strpos( $string, '<p> );
if( $pos !== false ){
    $string = substr_replace( $string, '<p>', $pos, 3 );
}
// Remove last occurrence of '<p>'
$pos = strrpos( $string, '</p>' );
if( $pos !== false ){
    $string = substr_replace( $string, '</p>', $pos, 3 );
}
```