# Split a string at last occurrence of a particular character string REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

`buynaturallesunfloweroil1ltrat78rupees`

now this string have two occurrences of `at`. `I want to split the string at`get`or`last occurrence of `at`.`

`Some strings can be like buynaturallesunfloweroilget1ltrat78rupees`

buyn`at`urallesunfloweroil1ltr`at`78rupees.

I want to split the string such that:

```
Arr[0] = buynaturallesunfloweroil1ltr

Arr[1] = 78rupees
```

Basically I have to split the string at last occurence of `at`. I am not very good at `preg_split`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strrpos` is enough.

Comment: would you please give me an example of that.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835636/php-replace-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string

Comment: Or `explode()` ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(.*)at(.*)
```

1. You get Arr[0] in group 1
2. Arr[1](https://regex101.com/r/apIT0O/4) in group 2

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/apIT0O/4)

Sample Code:

```
<?php

$re = '/(.*)at(.*)/s';
$str = 'buynaturallesunfloweroil1ltrat78rupees';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);

?>
```

Comment: and the reason is ?

Comment: `preg_split("/(.*)at(.*)/", "buynaturallesunfloweroil1ltrat78rupees"); ` is giving me empty array.

Comment: what if I want only arr[0] and arr[1].  `$matches` give me actually array of size 3.

Comment: No,  as it will break at each instance of 'at'

Comment: if you don't understand how regex thing work, then you need to know that, index zero contains the full match (full string) , and then comes the capture groups which is group 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

Try  this :

```
<?php
 $str = "buynaturallesunfloweroil1ltrat78rupees";

echo $filename = substr($file, 0, strrpos($str, 'at')); echo '---';
echo $extension = substr($file, strrpos($str, 'at') + 2);

?>
```

Comment: what is $file here ? and $extension ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code :

```
$str = "buynaturallesunfloweroil1ltrat78rupees";
$arr = explode('at', $str);
print_r(end($arr));
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my above answer. it was not fully functional:

here find the answer :

```
$str = "buynaturallesunfloweroil1ltrat78rupees";
echo $first = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, 'at')); echo '---';
echo $second = substr($str, strrpos($str, 'at') + 2);
```

Comment: you've posted 2 identical answers(by approach), why?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : the frist answer was not right and the naming convenstions were not proper.

Comment: so remove the improper one