# How to replace last comma in string with "and" using php?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, str-replace

I'm trying to replace the last occurence of a comma in a text with "and" using `strrchr()` and `str_replace()`.

Example:

```
$likes = 'Apple, Samsung, Microsoft';
$likes = str_replace(strrchr($likes, ','), ' and ', $likes);
```

But this replaces the entire last word (Microsoft in this case) including the last comma in this string. How can I just remove the last comma and replace it with " and " ?

I need to solve this using `strrchr()` as a function. That's why this question is no duplicate and more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Replace Last Occurence of a String in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3835653/5447994)

Comment: I saw that question. I need to solve this using `strrchr`.

Comment: @Thamilhan You should actually read the question first before reporting everything as duplicate...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To replace only the last occurrence, I think the better way is:

```
$likes = 'Apple, Samsung, Microsoft';
$likes = substr_replace($likes, ' and', strrpos($likes, ','), 1);
```

strrpos finds the position of last comma, and substr_replace puts the desired string in that place replacing '1' characters in this case.

Comment: If $likes='Apple' , this function returns ' andpple'

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex to find last comma in string. Php [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) replace string with another string by regex pattern.

```
$likes = 'Apple, Samsung, Microsoft';
$likes = preg_replace("/,([^,]+)$/", " and $1", $likes)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Spa7h)

Comment: you can also do `preg_replace('/,(?=[^,]*$)/',' and', $likes);`

Answer (score 4):

just provide the answer with function `strrchr()`

```
$likes = 'Apple, Samsung, Microsoft';
$portion = strrchr($likes, ',');
$likes = str_replace($portion, (" and" . substr($portion, 1, -1)), $likes);
```

because `strrchr()` will

> This function returns the portion of string

See [Doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)

so we just need only replace the comma symbol should be fine. and the comma will be always the first character when you use `strrchr()`

See [Demo here](https://3v4l.org/JSC7E)

Answer (score 1):

first, you gotta separate the elements into an array with all but the last one, and the last one. then you put them back together with commas and an "and", respectively

```
$likes = "A, B, C";
$likes_arr = explode(",", $likes);
$last = array_pop($likes_arr);
$likes = implode(",", $likes_arr) . " and" . $last;
echo $likes; //"A, B and C";
```

however: don't forget to check if you actually have enough elements. this fails for inputs without comma.

Comment: Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array

Comment: We can use 
if($last)
{

$likes = implode(",", $likes_arr) . " and" . $last;
echo $likes; //"A, B and C";
 
} for fails of input without comma

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran no. not in that way, because for the input "A", $likes_arr becomes ["A"], so $last will be "A" which evaluates to true.